# How I add a custom navigation bar button?

Tags: customization

I see Android 6/7 I can to customize the navigation bar ("back", "home" and "recent" buttons). I can reorder, remove or add other pre-defined buttons.

I want add new custom buttom. By example, I want a "screenshot" button to avoid hold down+power to do a screenshot.

Is it possible?

EDIT: My devices are LG K10 (2016 and 2017 versions)

Comment: Please add your device name. Some android devices doesn't have on screen navigation buttons. For such cases, it requires root access. https://www.guidingtech.com/screenshots-without-power-volume-button/, https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/customize-your-navigation-bar-android-nougat-no-root-needed-0177176/

Comment: LG k10 devices has on screen navigation buttons. This link may help you to edit navigation buttons. https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS985/Userguide/042.html